# netlogo: Comparing turtles variables

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a simulation with two armies facing each other. To distinguish both armies I set a variable *ex* to check if there are enemies in a turtle's neighbors.

Here what I have:

```
breed [sols sol]
sols-own[en ex nvic]
```

This is what I tried to do (failing):

```
ifelse any? sols-on neighbors with [ex != ([ex] of myself)]
[
;fight
]
[
;move
]
```

But *with* is checking those patches instead of the turtles, and I got no idea how to do it.

Kindly appreciate your help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: in my case myself isn't working so I replaced with self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get away with just putting parentheses around `sols-on neighbors` to specify the agentset you're trying to evaluate with `with`:

```
breed [sols sol]
sols-own[ex]

to setup  
  ca
  create-sols 20 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set ex "good"
    set color blue
  ]
  ask n-of 10 sols [
    set ex "evil"
    set color red
  ]
  reset-ticks  
end


to detect-enemies
  ask sols [
    ifelse any? ( sols-on neighbors ) with [ ex != [ex]  of myself ] [
      print "ENEMY DETECTED"
    ] [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick  
end
```

Comment: thx, helped me a lot, although I still got errors in my code, which by now have been dealt